# Maven transitive dependency locked on version although updating the main one

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a dependency declared as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the `dependency:tree` dump for it is

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.7:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.7:provided
```

i have a snyk scan that complains about vulnerability in `spring-expression` so i wanted to update the `spring-context` but after updating it with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.27</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

i am getting the following `dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.27:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.7:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.7:provided
```

as you can see `spring-expression` is still `5.3.7` how to set it to the proper fixed version?

Comment: Don't update parts of Spring separately. Update all of it at once.

Comment: Good advice from Jorn... how are you using spring via bom or via spring boot? Can you show more of your pom's...

Comment: @Jorn i am not the owner of this project, it does not use spring besides this one library